# Find f(x) given that $f(ax)$=$\frac{1}{a}f(x)$ and $\int^{ab}_a f(x) dx\equiv\int^b_1 f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, functions

Find f(x) given that $f(ax)$=$\frac{1}{a}f(x)$ and $\int^{ab}_a f(x) dx\equiv\int^b_1 f(x)dx$. I have no idea how to tackle this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x/a$, then $dx=ady$, we have 
\begin{align*}\int_a^{ab}f(x)dx&=\int_1^b f(ay)\cdot ady\\
&=\int_1^b af(ay)dy\\
&=\int_1^b f(y)dy\quad\text{ (Use previous condition)}\end{align*}

So the first condition actually just implies the second condition. We just need to find $f(x)$ satisfy just the first condition. For instance, $f(x)=1/x$ will do the job.